# Excel/VBA: Format or round number inside of a string

Tags: excel, vba

So I've got large strings like the following:

`bread 54,23424%, butter 15,521424%, chocolate 0,02142%`

the output should be

`bread 54%, butter 16%, chocolate`

and need to round them financially to the 2 integer point.
So long I got a function that searches for the parts I need to trim, but I need to get a round to that.

Th function takes arguments like

regExchange(; "reg. Pattern"; "Replace Pattern")

The function so long is:

```
    Function regExchange(MyRange As Range, strPattern As String, strReplace As String) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = MyRange.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            regExchange = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            regExchange = "Muster nicht gefunden"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

PS: The Pattern may contain more or less than these 3 objects which I get as a string, like above.

Comment: Is it comma or a dot in 54,23424?

Comment: The input only contains comma, no dots.

Comment: So divide each number by 100'000 then set the number format to percent with no decimal places `NumberFormat = "0%"`

Comment: To do just that, I first need a way to automatically get the numbers out of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using split is a good way to parse strings like that. Maybe splitting at the blanks is a better way to parse the values and round them to the desired results:

```
Function Round_Numbers(Text As String) As String
Dim Arr, I As Integer, pos As Integer
    Arr = Split(Text, " ")
    For I = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        pos = InStrRev(Arr(I), "%")
        If pos > 0 Then
            Arr(I) = Round(Val(Replace(Left(Arr(I), pos - 1), ",", ".")), 0) & "%" & IIf(I < UBound(Arr), ",", "")
        End If

    Next I
Round_Numbers = Join(Arr, " ")
End Function
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. <3

Answer (score 0):

Use the below, assuming the range is K22

```
=MID(K22,1,SEARCH(".",K22)-1)&IF(MID(K22,SEARCH(".",K22)+1,1) >4,"."&MID(K22,SEARCH(".",K22)+1,1)+1&"%","."&MID(K22,SEARCH(".",K22)+1,1)&"%")
```

Comment: Since I can't use this in vba, I need a loop to do this with every single word.